# Can I assign a structure to another field structure?

Tags: c, structure, assign

I am working I C with two structures: Car and List

```
#define MAX_LEN 10
#define NUM 7
typedef struct{
     char nr[NUM];
     char model[MAX_LEN];
     char categ[];
}Car;

#define LEN 100
typedef struct{
     Car elem[LEN];
     int n;
}List;
```

I want to add elements of type `car` into the `List`. I have tried

```
void add(List l, Car c){
      l.elem[l.n] = c;
      l.n ++;
}
```

but when I print the list I get weird characters and I suspect here is the problem.

Comment: So the problem surfaces when you're trying to print, but we *don't* get to see the code that does the printing? That's cruel and unusual.

Comment: (There is actually a problem with the code you've shown, but it hasn't to do with your printing problems.)

Comment: read about passing arguments to the function, what you do is creating a copy of a car and a copy of a list and adding this new car to the new list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 void add(List* l, Car c){

        strcpy(l->elem[l->n].nr,c.nr);
        strcpy(l->elem[l->n].model,c.model);
        strcpy(l->elem[l->n].categ,c.categ);
        l->n= l->n + 1;
  }
```

Comment: This wont compile. You passed l as pointer so to access n, -> must be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `List` by `pointer` and receive accordingly

```
// Call
add(&l,c);

//Function 
void add(List* l, Car c){
    l->elem[l->n] = c;
    l->n++;
}
```